# pytest-django run with migrations ignores database triggers

Tags: django, postgresql, pytest, database-trigger, pytest-django

My Django app depends on a database with some triggers setup. I use [this part of the documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#randomize-database-sequences) to set up the triggers in the test database for the pytest runner.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute([...])  # Set it up
```

I run my tests with `--nomigrations` and it works as expected. Without `--nomigrations` (test runs migrations first), the triggers are not working.

So trying to debug this, I've confirmed

1. The fixture *IS* run, so the triggers *SHOULD* be setup
2. Pausing execution in the debugger at the start of my tests, I can confirm that the triggers *ARE* created and present in the test database (by running `psql test_<mydb>` and looking in the `pg_trigger` table)
3. Pausing execution inside my fixture, I can confirm that migrations are run before the fixture. So the migrations may setup the triggers for me, and they may do it incorrectly, but the fixture will drop all the triggers and recreate them
4. Removing the fixture and running with migrations provide no new results. So there is no  reason to think that the fixture is the problem. It seems to be only due to the migrations being run

Let me just stress once more that **the tests pass when run without migrations** and testing the functionality when running the dev server against my dev db I can also confirm that it works

So, my question is: Is there any reason that running with migrations should do things differently? Or is it likely that my migrations do something obscure which makes things fail, i.e. it is my own fault?

Comment: any reason you are not using the django test framework?

Comment: @e4c5 Much too slow. Many extra benefits of the pytest library

Answer (score 0):

Placing trigger in `django_db_setup` worked for me

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''CREATE TRIGGER search_vector_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
            ON xml_templates_template FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
            tsvector_update_trigger(search_vector, 'pg_catalog.english', name, description, info);
        ''')
```

pytest (4.4.1) is run with `--nomigrations`